# Watch is not working on serverless mongo thats working on normal cluster but not on serverless instance

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, watch

// <kbd>Watch</kbd> the schema for changes

```
const changeStream = betSchema.watch();

changeStream.on('change', async (change) => {
    console.log("Change is ", change);
    console.log("Changes occurred")

    if (change.operationType === 'insert') {
        const updated = await betSchema.findOne({ _id: change.documentKey._id });
        // console.log("Updated is ", updated)
        const data  = await getBetsForTimeCategorized();
        getBetForParticularBetIdUsingStreams.emit("bet-found", {
            status: true,
            message: "Bet Updated",
            "data": data,
        });
        }
});
```

this one is working when i am using free cluster of mongo but when i am using the mongo from serverless instance its not working

i was trying to watch on the schema but not working when i am using serverless

Comment: The [Serverless Instances Limitations documentation page](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/reference/serverless-instance-limitations/) directly states: "_Serverless instances don't support change streams._"